# switching voltage rail to lower relay voltage

Tags: transistors, relay

I would need to lower the power of my relay after it has been closed.
To do this ( I'm switching AC with this relay) I intercept the relay output with a db107 bridge rectifier and isolate the signal with ltv816 optocouplers.

This first part seems to work.

then signal arrive then to SN74LVC1G3157 that should activate the output when receive the signal from the switch and activate 5v or 12v rail. rail are controlled by 2 2n2222A.

This unfortunately not works, the power remain always at 12v, seems the transistor not open.

Do you have some easier suggestions or see the error ?

here the schematics:
[image]

Comment: I don't see any MOSFETs in your circuit. I think you mean BJT.

Comment: What is an SN74LCV3157 ? Are you sure that is the right part number? Google doesn't seem to have heard of it.

Comment: typo in the text,  the schematic has the strait dope (it's an amalogie mux/demux like CD4053)

Comment: I can't see any way to get more than 2.1V out of that circuit,  are you sure it's constructed as drawn?

Comment: hello , would u suggest a different approach ?? I'm beginner and I can't find the right way to approach the problem

Comment: this is exactly what I'm trying to achieve https://www.geek-share.com/detail/2628158780.html